# select specific face by its index

Tags: python, scripting, mesh

How do I select a specific face within a mesh knowing its face index or vertex?
I tried without success:

```
bpy.data.meshes.polygons[2].select=True #where the face index=2
```

Answer (score 28):

The line below is invalid.

```
bpy.data.meshes.polygons[2].select = True
```

`bpy.data.meshes` is a collection of all meshes in this .blend file, it doesn't have an attribute `.polygons`. You are close though, you need to reference a specific  mesh either via

```
mesh = bpy.data.objects['some_object_name'].data
# or
mesh = bpy.data.meshes['some_mesh_name']
```

Important to note here that Objects are not the same as Meshes

- An Object can hold a reference to a Mesh. (or Curves, or other Types)
- A Mesh only holds references to the objects that use it. (Actually, I think it only holds the count of objects that reference it.. not their names: maybe someone can correct me?)

#### In Object Mode

One way to select by face index is, go to Object Mode first then do

```
obj = bpy.context.active_object
obj.data.polygons[2].select = True
```

When you go back to Edit Mode you'll see the face is selected.

#### In Edit Mode

If you wanted to do that in Edit Mode, this might be unintuitive at first, but it involves a little more code. Blender  comes with a useful collection of templates for mesh editing. The relevant template for this question can be found in Text Editor > Templates > Python > Bmesh Simple Edit Mode.

Below is a slight modification to that template, copy it to the Text Editor and press Run.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

# notice in Bmesh polygons are called faces
bm.faces[4].select = True  # select index 4

# Show the updates in the viewport
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)
```

### for 3.0

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

# notice in Bmesh polygons are called faces
bm.faces[4].select = True  # select index 4

# Show the updates in the viewport
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Comment: yes no reference just number of users, it will be redundant to store the relation on both sides

Comment: cool,  don't recall ever really needing that information anyway.. just wondering!

Comment: Thanks, this works great,  the key is to do this in object mode.

Comment: You may need to do `bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()` before `bm.faces[4].select = True  # select index 4`

Comment: I noticed that sometimes `obj.data.polygons[0].select = True` doesn't select the face. even when doing a loop `for face in obj.data.polygons: face.select = True`. sometimes nothing happens, nothing is selected. but the bmesh way does always work. so something's wrong with obj.data.polygons[0].select