# How to assign a material to a single face of a mesh using Python API

Tags: python, bmesh

I have tried the following but the mat is not assigned to any of the faces.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

# Creating a new Mat
mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="newMat")
mat.diffuse_color = (0.5,0,0.5,1)        

# Generating a Box
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2,  enter_editmode=True, location=(0, 0, 0))

# Resizing and Translating the box
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(0.5, 1, 1))
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0.5, 0, 0))
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')

# Instantiating the bmesh of the Box
obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

# Selecting just one of the faces
bm.faces[0].select = True      


# toggle to edit mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

# make sure face select mode is enabled
bpy.context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode = [False, False, True]


# use second material slot
ob = bpy.context.active_object
ob.active_material_index = 1


# assign the material
bpy.ops.object.material_slot_assign()

# toggle to object mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

What am I doing wrong, or how else could I achieve this?

Comment: @MartyFouts hi, thanks for shareing. Actually I tried that answer, I should have mentioned in the question that most of my code have been taken from the accepted answer, but in my case the mat is not being assigned. That is why I posted my version

Comment: No problem.  In the future, you should mention the specific answers you have tried and why they didn't work for you.  The answer from the question should work, but the code you shared is missing some of the  steps. Someone has already posted another way of doing it. If you want to see your code fixed, let me know and I'll post an answer with working bmesh-based code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can assign the materials using [`MeshPolygon.material_index`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.MeshPolygon.html?highlight=polygon%20material_index#bpy.types.MeshPolygon.material_index) in *Object Mode* without [Bmesh](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.html?highlight=bmesh#module-bmesh).

[image]

```
import bpy

def create_material(mat_name, diffuse_color=(1,1,1,1)):
    mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name=mat_name)
    mat.diffuse_color = diffuse_color
    return mat

# Generate 2 demo materials
mat_red = create_material("Red", (1,0,0,1))
mat_green = create_material("Green", (0,1,0,1))

# Generating a Box
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, location=(0, 0, 0))
# Resizing and Translating the box ...

# Get a reference to the object in context
obj = bpy.context.object

# Append both Materials to the created object
obj.data.materials.append(mat_red)
obj.data.materials.append(mat_green)

# Assign the green Material to the second polygon 
obj.data.polygons[1].material_index = 1

# Assign the green Material to the 4th polygon 
obj.data.polygons[3].material_index = 1
```

Related:

- [Python - Set material to material slot](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8475/python-set-material-to-material-slot)
- [2.93.4 Python - apply an image texture to part of a mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/240341/2-93-4-python-apply-an-image-texture-to-part-of-a-mesh)
- [How to assign a new material to an object in the scene from Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23433/how-to-assign-a-new-material-to-an-object-in-the-scene-from-python)
- [select specific face by its index](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28892/select-specific-face-by-its-index)

Comment: Thanks, very informative, I will give it a try Today and let you know

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 7):

If you'd like to assign material(s) to certain faces in *Edit Mode*, just assign the index of the *material slot* to [`BMFace.material_index`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.types.html?highlight=bmesh%20material_index#bmesh.types.BMFace.material_index) on a [Bmesh representation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.html?highlight=bmesh#module-bmesh) of your mesh:

[image]

```
import bpy, bmesh

def create_material(mat_name, diffuse_color=(1,1,1,1)):
    mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name=mat_name)
    mat.diffuse_color = diffuse_color
    return mat

# Generate 2 demo materials
mat_red = create_material("Red", (1,0,0,1))
mat_green = create_material("Green", (0,1,0,1))

# Generate a Box
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, enter_editmode=True, location=(0, 0, 0))
# Resize and Translate the box ...

# Get a reference to the object in context
obj = bpy.context.object

# Append both Materials to the created object
obj.data.materials.append(mat_red)
obj.data.materials.append(mat_green)

# Bmesh representation
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()

# Assign the green Material to the second polygon
bm.faces[1].material_index = 1

# Assign the green Material to the 4th polygon 
bm.faces[3].material_index = 1

# Optional
#bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
#bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

*You might want to create the mesh using Bmesh in this case as well: [how to use BMesh to add verts, faces, and edges to existing geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/414/how-to-use-bmesh-to-add-verts-faces-and-edges-to-existing-geometry)*