# how to move cursor in uv viewport to selected? And how to fix the error?

Tags: python, uv

Why gives an error on bpy.ops.uv.snap_cursor(target='SELECTED') ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to find the UV editor area that interests you. This will apply the operator in the first visible UV editor it finds:

```py
>>> imgeds = [a for a in C.window_manager.windows[0].screen.areas if a.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR']
>>> uved = next(i for i in imgeds if [s for s in i.spaces if s.mode=='UV'])
>>> bpy.ops.uv.snap_cursor({'area': uved}, target='SELECTED')
```

Comment: thank you very match

Comment: C.window_manager.windows[0].screen.areas - what C ?

Comment: NameError: name 'C' is not defined

Comment: How create text data-blok with this code without error ?

Comment: How to select a specific object, for example 'Plane', to perform these actions on it ?

Comment: in console `C` is an alias for `bpy.context`. You can create such an alias in a script by `C = bpy.context` or `from bpy import context as C`

Comment: @tormozzzz [Selecting an object via scripting?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/38618/60486), [select specific face by its index](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/28892/60486)

Comment: https://pastenow.ru/3fa07acae3f883177197bbbe42bb1ed9

Comment: ![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31005234/143927581-fd1b8212-7035-47af-90f1-09b8418db2d7.png) - this is screenshot

Comment: @tormozzzz as I wrote in my answer: *"This will apply the operator in the first visible UV editor it finds"* - your problem is that it doesn't find any visible UV editors, perhaps because you don't have a UV editor open in current workspace. How about you go to the **UV Editing** workspace, split one of areas there, make it a text editor, and there paste and run your script?